# how to change "height" element value in XS (extra small) bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

how can i change the value of my "height" element when the device or width/height changes? my default height size is 180px (that's a rectangle in LG(large screen) but the height doesn't change when i try visit in mobile device (XS) mode.
i want to increase the value of "height" when someone visits website from XS or mobile devices.

i"m using bootstrap 3.3.7 in my project.

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Defining Proper Media Queries**
>
> Bootstrap has clearly defined breakpoints for different kinds of
>   devices, specified by using CSS media queries. The following are the
>   breakpoint categories used for the different types of devices:
>
> - **Extra Small Devices** (e.g. cell phones) are the default, creating the “mobile first” concept in Bootstrap. This covers devices
>     smaller    than 768px wide.
> - **“Small Devices”** (e.g. tablets) are targeted with @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { ... }.

https://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-web-design-tips-bootstrap-css/